# Protractor: Expect 'pop up window to be visible' statement not working

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, aurelia, e2e-testing

I'm running an automated test where a user places a bid and clicks on 'place bid' button, after the button click, a pop up window appears. I want to add an Expect statement to test that the pop up window appears but I get a `no element found using locator` error when  I run the spec file.
This is the HTML

```html
<ai-dialog class="au-target" au-target-id="268">
<ai-dialog-header class="au-target" au-target-id="269">
<div class="dialog-header-content">
<h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Bid</h4><!--slot-->
</div>
</ai-dialog-header><ai-dialog-body class="au-target" au-target-id="270">
<div class="text-md m-b-lg _500">
Are you sure you want to want to apply the following bid?
</ai-dialog-body><ai-dialog-footer class="au-target" au-target-id="275">
 <button class="primary au-target" click.trigger="ok()" au-target-id="276">Ok</button><button class="btn-danger au-target" click.trigger="cancel()" au-target-id="277">Cancel</button>
 </ai-dialog-footer>
  </ai-dialog>
```

This is a section of the page object file

```js
placeBidButton.click();
browser.sleep(500);
expect(element(by.name('<ai-dialog class="au-target" au-target-id="268">')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

When I run the test, the pop up window does appear.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your identifier to 
`expect(element(by.css(".modal-title").isDisplayed()).toBeTrue();`

Comment: `expect(element(by.css(".modal-title").isDisplayed()).toBe(true);` or `expect(element(by.css(".modal-title").isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();`